# Removing a string from a list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

One of the columns in my dataframe is a list. Here is what it looks like -

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['a','b'] |
| 2 | ['b'] |

I want to remove the string b from the list in Column2. I am trying the following -

```
df=df['Column2'].map(lambda x: if 'b' in x then x.remove('b'))
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Wrong dupe, so reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change logic - filter all values if not `b`:

```
df['Column2']=df['Column2'].map(lambda x: [y for y in x if y != 'b'])
```

Or:

```
df['Column2']=df['Column2'].map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y!= 'b', x)))

print (df)
   Column1 Column2
0        1     [a]
1        2      []
```

Pandas solution possible, more complicated, so slowier:

```
df['Column2']=df['Column2'].explode().loc[lambda x: x != 'b'].groupby(level=0).agg(list).reindex(df.index, fill_value=[])
```